# How to fix when React JS Pagination component does Nothing on Click?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, pagination, components

Im using react js Pagination component and wrote the code as mentioned in documentation but it does nothing onClick.

> import Pagination from "react-js-pagination"

and here i use it:

```js
{this.state.spareParts.map((part, index) =>
    <Col md="3" lg="3" sm="6" xs="6" xl="3">
     <Card>
      <h4>
       <b> {part.Name}  </b>
      </h4>
      <h4> Rs. {part.Price}  </h4>
      <h5> By: {part.CompanyName} </h5>
     </Card>
    </Col>
 )}

<Pagination
          data={this.state.spareParts}
              activePage={this.state.activePage}
              itemsCountPerPage={10}
              totalItemsCount={50}
              pageRangeDisplayed={5}
              onChange={this.handlePageChange} />
```

and here is handlePageChange function:

```js
handlePageChange(pageNumber)
{
 console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
 this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
}
```

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong here becoz of which Im getting no results on click on pagination bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Can you try below code.

Why do you need to send `data`(`spareParts`) as the component doesn't take `data` as prop.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activePage: 15
    };
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Pagination
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={10}
          totalItemsCount={450}
          pageRangeDisplayed={5}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did same code as above but it shows me only a pagination bar. What I want from this bar to show only selected items(from this.state.spareParts) on my page but shows all same items either I click on page 1 or 3 or any.

Comment: I m sending data as I dont know how would this Pagination component know that on which data it has to apply pagination on.

Comment: You have to filter data in handlePageChange and not by passing data to `Pagination` component. `Pagination` component should not know your data.

Comment: Do I have to make another API call to fetch a limited data for the page? How would It fetch different data for each page?

Comment: There are two ways, either get all the data and then filter inside `handlePage` function  based on `activePage` or if the data is big then for every page change hit the api.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who looking for solutions in 2022

```
// Try to add event.stopPropagation();
       <a className={`page-link ${page == props.currentPage ? 'isDisabled-link' : ''}`} href="#"
                    onClick={(event) => { event.stopPropagation(); props.pageChanged(page) }}
        >
           {page}
     </a>
```